# Prove that any two terms of the sequence must have the same value

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Consider the sequence of numbers

$ \ a,a^2, a^4, a^8 , ............., \ (mod \ N) \ $

such that $ gcd(a,N)=1 \ $ and $ \ N \ $ is an **odd prime**.
Then

(i) Prove that $ \exists \ $ two terms of the sequence  having the same value.

(ii) Prove that $ \ a^x \equiv 1 \ (mod \ N) \ $

**Answer:**

(i)

Given $ \ gcd(a,N)=1 \ $

Then there exits $ \ m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \ $ such that $ \ ma+nN=1 \ $

We will show that for any $ n=2l , \ l \in \mathbb{N} ,  \ \ \ a^{2l}=(a^{2l})^{2} \ \ (mod \ N)  $

Since $ \ N \ $ is odd prime , we have

$$ N \neq 2 $$

**But next I can not prove it.**

Help me doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$N=3$ is an odd prime, $a=2$ is coprime with $N$, yet $a\equiv2\bmod3$ and $a^2\equiv1\bmod3$.

What you probably mean is not that **any** two terms have the same value, but **there are** two terms which have the same value. This is a consequence of the pigeonhole principle, given that the sequence is infinite and there are finitely many residues modulo $N$.

As for the second question, what you probably mean is that this equation can be solved for $x$. To do so, from Part 1. you have $a^p\equiv a^q$, assuming $p<q$, you can deduce $1\equiv a^{q-p}\mod N$.

Comment: yes absolutely .

Comment: How to prove part $ (i) \ $  mathematically ?

Comment: The pigeonhole principle is definitely a mathematical way. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: How does the condition $ \ N \ $ is odd prime works here? I mean what is the contribution of $ \ N \ $ being odd prime?

Comment: It doesn't. The result is true for $N=2$ as well, but in this case the elements of the sequence are indeed all equal to each other, and they are equal to $1\bmod 2$.